# How to update Google Maps marker position without them duplicating?

Tags: javascript, loops, google-maps-api-3, setinterval, google-maps-api-2

I’m making API call every 15seconds and updating a marker position inside my loop. It works, except that after the update the old marker stays and a new one stacks on top of it. I couldn’t come up with the logic to fix this. I tried using booleans, that did not work. Now I’m checking if planeIcon is not defined then initialize a new marker and if it is defined then just .setPosition(). This gives me no errors but the icons either does not appear on to the screen at all or starts stacking. What I’m doing wrong?

```
var map, marker1, marker2, myLatlng, icon;
var boo = true;
var planeIcon = [];
function initMap() {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it an array of styles,
    // and the name to be displayed on the map type control.
setInterval(
function () {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8888/lsapp/public/planes/')
        .then(function (response) {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var north = new google.maps.LatLng(90.0000, 0.0000);
            var northPole = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: 90.0000, lng: 0.0000},
                map: map
            });
            northPole.setIcon({
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 10),
                scale: 6
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                //console.log(response.data["states"][i]);
                console.log(response.data["states"][i]);

                var direction = new google.maps.LatLng(response.data["states"][i][6], response.data["states"][i][5]);
                var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(direction, north);

                myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(response.data["states"][i][6],response.data["states"][i][5]);
                    icon = {
                        path: "M 356.26958,135.02702 L 356.26958,249.31026 L 296.72689,289.12758 C 298.37366,285.78981 297.94877,282.22185 297.97085,278.70356 L 297.7704,238.6142 L 268.80878,238.44964 L 269.05561,285.18318 C  ",
                        fillColor: '#111111',
                        fillOpacity: 1,
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(0.01, 0.01),
                        rotation: heading + response.data["states"][i][10],
                        scale: 0.02
                    }

                    if(planeIcon.length > 0) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < planeIcon.length; j++)
                        planeIcon[j].setPosition(myLatlng);
                    } else {
                        planeIcon.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: {lat: response.data["states"][i][6], lng: response.data["states"][i][5]},
                            map: map,
                            title: response.data["states"][i][1],
                            icon: icon
                        }));
                    }
                    console.log(planeIcon);
```

......

Working snippet: https://codepen.io/Limpuls/full/rgpKjy

I made an array and push all new marker objects to it. Then I check if array length is more than 0 then just setLocation() if no then init new marker. Unfortunately it only outputs one plane instead of 50 and every 15seconds it updates not a plane location but puts a totally new random plane location. Like it was Thailand before, then its USA.

Axios fetches every 15 secs and you can see icons stacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the API](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html) you are using, the first entry is a unique identifier for the aircraft.

One option would be to make an array of markers with that unique id as the key.  When new data arrives, update the markers by that unique id.  Then stale markers can be removed when data hasn't been received for a marker for a long enough time.

```
  // in the global scope
  var planesArray = [];

  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < response.data["states"].length; i++) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(response.data["states"][i][6], response.data["states"][i][5]);
    // limit to the planes currently in view on the map
    if (!bounds.contains(myLatlng))
      continue;
    inBoundCnt++;
    var direction = new google.maps.LatLng(response.data["states"][i][6], response.data["states"][i][5]);
    var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(direction, north);
    icon.rotation = heading + response.data["states"][i][10];

    var uniqueId = response.data["states"][i][0];
    // if marker doesn't already exist, make a new one
    if (!planesArray[uniqueId] || !planesArray[uniqueId].setPosition) {
      var planeIcon = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: response.data["states"][i][1],
        icon: icon,
        uniqueId: uniqueId,
        displayCnt: 0,
        timeStamp: now
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(planeIcon, 'click', (function(planeIcon, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(response.data["states"][i][0].toLowerCase());
          infowindow.open(map, planeIcon);
          console.log(response.data["states"][i][0].toLowerCase());
        }
      })(planeIcon, i));
      planesArray[uniqueId] = planeIcon;
    } else {
      // if marker already exists, change its position
      planesArray[uniqueId].setPosition(myLatlng);
      planesArray[uniqueId].displayCnt++;
      planesArray[uniqueId].timeStamp = Date.now();
    }
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jdwfz054/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map, marker1, marker2, myLatlng, icon;
var boo = true;
var planeIcon;
var planesArray = [];

function initMap() {
  icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(0.01, 0.01);
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  setInterval(
    function() {
      axios.get('https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all')

        .then(function(response) {
          var now = Date.now();
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var north = new google.maps.LatLng(90.0000, 0.0000);
          var northPole = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
              lat: 90.0000,
              lng: 0.0000
            },
            map: map
          });
          northPole.setIcon({
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 10),
            scale: 6
          });
          var bounds = map.getBounds();
          console.log("processing " + response.data["states"].length + " entries");
          var inBoundCnt = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < response.data["states"].length /* && i < 50 */ ; i++) {
            // console.log(i + ":" + response.data["states"][i]);
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(response.data["states"][i][6], response.data["states"][i][5]);
            if (!bounds.contains(myLatlng))
              continue;
            inBoundCnt++;
            var direction = new google.maps.LatLng(response.data["states"][i][6], response.data["states"][i][5]);
            var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(direction, north);
            icon.rotation = heading + response.data["states"][i][10];

            var uniqueId = response.data["states"][i][0];
            if (!planesArray[uniqueId] || !planesArray[uniqueId].setPosition) {
              var planeIcon = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: response.data["states"][i][1],
                icon: icon,
                uniqueId: uniqueId,
                displayCnt: 0,
                timeStamp: now
              });
              google.maps.event.addListener(planeIcon, 'click', (function(planeIcon, i) {
                return function() {
                  axios.get('http://localhost:8888/lsapp/public/planes/' + response.data["states"][i][0].toLowerCase())
                    .then(function(res) {
                      div.innerHTML = '';
                      div.innerHTML += "<h5>" + res.data + "</h5>";
                    }).catch(function(error) {
                      // handle error
                      console.log(error);
                    });
                  infowindow.setContent(response.data["states"][i][0].toLowerCase());
                  infowindow.open(map, planeIcon);
                  console.log(response.data["states"][i][0].toLowerCase());
                }
              })(planeIcon, i));
              planesArray[uniqueId] = planeIcon;
            } else {
              // console.log("[" + i + "] moving " + uniqueId + " to " + myLatlng.toUrlValue(6));
              planesArray[uniqueId].setPosition(myLatlng);
              planesArray[uniqueId].displayCnt++;
              planesArray[uniqueId].timeStamp = Date.now();
            }
          }
          console.log("in bounds markers=" + inBoundCnt);
          // remove stale markers
          for (plane in planesArray) {
            var deltaT = now - planesArray[plane].timeStamp;
            // console.log("plane="+plane+" uniqueId="+planesArray[plane].uniqueId+" deltaT="+deltaT);
            if (deltaT > 10000) {
              console.log("removing " + plane + " deltaT=" + deltaT);
              planesArray[plane].setMap(null);
              delete planesArray[plane];
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(function() {
          // always executed
        });

    }, 10000);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 40.7127753,
      lng: -74.0059728
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
}
var icon = {
  path: "M 356.26958,135.02702 L 356.26958,249.31026 L 296.72689,289.12758 C 298.37366,285.78981 297.94877,282.22185 297.97085,278.70356 L 297.7704,238.6142 L 268.80878,238.44964 L 269.05561,285.18318 C 269.06227,292.68821 270.04683,297.17053 276.7074,301.30953 L 204.8529,348.4504 C 207.01499,345.12276 206.84863,341.2911 206.84863,337.51874 L 206.77165,295.05645 L 178.71508,294.89191 L 178.6328,342.1191 C 178.84508,349.00225 179.88792,356.28465 186.12004,360.54922 L 30.615857,462.16174 C 3.2664942,481.49054 8.4728732,501.69026 10.293349,521.73054 L 356.26958,404.23849 L 356.26958,582.78033 L 365.64921,648.51992 L 252.92924,731.45549 C 236.829,745.21163 238.89783,759.656 241.98635,773.74604 L 388.44003,735.48708 C 390.1301,775.95885 408.69374,776.66877 411.55996,735.56935 L 558.01364,773.82832 C 561.10216,759.73826 563.17099,745.29391 547.07076,731.53776 L 434.3508,648.6022 L 443.73041,582.86261 L 443.73041,404.32077 L 789.70665,521.73054 C 791.52713,501.6903 796.7335,481.57282 769.38414,462.24402 L 613.87995,360.6315 C 620.11205,356.3669 621.07263,349.08453 621.28491,342.20138 L 621.28491,294.97418 L 593.22834,295.13873 L 593.15851,338.35476 C 593.1282,342.1754 593.2504,345.43211 595.47226,348.97078 L 523.21031,301.39181 C 529.87094,297.25281 530.93773,292.77049 530.94439,285.26546 L 531.19122,238.53192 L 502.22959,238.69647 L 502.02452,278.95408 C 502.0435,282.62018 501.76549,285.90838 503.64551,289.27217 L 443.73041,249.39253 L 443.73041,135.10929 C 429.29576,-9.7066548 372.45267,-10.54689 356.26958,135.02702 z ",
  fillColor: '#111111',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  scale: 0.02
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you really helped me, because I was stuck on this for long time. I just have two questions. Are we using map.getBounds() for performance reasons? To retrieve data and display icons for the given map area and no more than is needed? And how this code exactly is working? if(!bounds.contains(myLatlng)) continue; inBoundCnt++; Is it checking if current map boundaries contains Lat and Lng and if not then skip the loop and continue with other iteration?

Comment: Yes, that limits the markers on the map to those in view.  The original code processed the first 50 records.  As the order seemed to not be consistent, that didn't seem to be a good way to limit the markers being displayed.

Comment: Yeah, that’s really smart, I didn’t know about bounds in google maps api. And what about delta time. Is it the same delta time people talk about in game development? I never used that and not sure whats going on. I see you are checking if delta time is more than 10000ms (same as our setInterval timer) then delete icon from map by using .setMap(null) and remove planes from array, right? So if we were not using delta time, this would not have worked? Can’t we just remove the planes inside setInterval function every 10000ms before putting new ones on the map?

Comment: That is deleting "stale" entries.